# Error: hosting:channel:deploy is not a Firebase command

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm trying to preview my firebase website and share with the following command:

```
firebase hosting:channel:deploy "testing_changes"
```

but I keep getting `Error: hosting:channel:deploy is not a Firebase command`

I've also tried not passing a string and just the word but I get the same error. I'm positive I'm in the root directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as per [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/10/preview-channels-firebase-hosting.html), you need to have `firebase-tools >= 8.12.0`.

run `firebase --version` in a terminal to view your currently installed version of firebase-tools.

to update `firebase-tools` write `npm i -g firebase-tools` in a terminal.

if you are on linux `sudo npm i -g firebase-tools`.

Comment: Why do you suggest doing it with sudo? Working perfectly with user role.

Comment: depending on how you installed npm, the folder where global libraries is created might require sudo access to write into